# How to equally distribute spaces among multi-columns

Tags: tables, floats

I have a table with a horizontal title above the multi-columns. In some cases, the horizontal title is wider than the multi-columns. This result in non-equally distributed columns that does not look nice. I need to fix this issue by equally distribute the columns among the space. This is a sample script with afigure.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pifont}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pifont
\newcommand{\cmark}{\ding{51}}
\newcommand{\xmark}{\ding{55}}
\newcommand*\rot{\rotatebox{90}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table} 
\caption{MyTable}
\centering
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!} {
\begin{tabular} {@{} lc*{14}l @{}}
\hline
\\ 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Column1} 
&&\multicolumn{3}{c}{Column2}    
&&\multicolumn{3}{c}{ColumnLongTitle}  
&&\multicolumn{2}{c}{Column3}  
&&\multicolumn{2}{c}{Column4}  
\\
\cmidrule(lr){1-1} 
\cmidrule(lr){3-5} 
\cmidrule(lr){7-9}
\cmidrule(lr){11-12}
\cmidrule(lr){14-15}
\\
& \vline &\rot{Title1} & \rot{Title2} & \rot{Title3} 
& \vline & \rot{Title1} & \rot{Title2} & \rot{Title3} 
& \vline & \rot{Title1} & \rot{Title2} 
& \vline & \rot{Title1} & \rot{Title2} 
\\ \hline
Row1 & \vline & {} & \cmark & {} & \vline & \cmark & {} & {} & \vline &  & \cmark & \vline & \cmark & {} &  \\
\hline
Row2 & \vline & \cmark & {} & {} & \vline & \cmark & {} & {} & \vline & {} & \cmark & \vline & \cmark & {} &  \\
\hline
Row3 & \vline & {} & \cmark & {} & \vline & \cmark & {} & {} & \vline & {} & \cmark & \vline & \cmark & {} &  \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT 2:** I tried the solution provided by @Bernard. But, there is another problem. When I need to add long text in the first row, the whole table get distorted. Can you clarify how to avoid such problem. My text length varies. I have quite long text in the most left cell in each row. This is an example of script you can run to see the issue.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
%\usepackage{showframe}
%\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.3pt}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx, caption, makecell}
\setcellgapes{3pt}
\usepackage{pifont}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pifont
\newcommand{\cmark}{\ding{51}}
\newcommand{\xmark}{\ding{55}}
\newcommand*\rot{\rotatebox{90}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\caption{MyTable}
\centering\makegapedcells
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} l|*{3}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} |*{3}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}| *{2}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}| *{2}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}|@{}}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Column1}
&\multicolumn{3}{c}{Column2}
&\multicolumn{3}{c}{ColumnLongTitle}
&\multicolumn{2}{c}{Column3}
&\multicolumn{2}{c}{Column4}
\\
\cmidrule(lr){1-1}
\cmidrule(lr){2-4}
\cmidrule(lr){5-7}
\cmidrule(lr){8-9}
\cmidrule(lr){10-11}
\addlinespace
 &\rot{Title1} & \rot{Title2} & \rot{Title3}
 & \rot{Title1} & \rot{Title2} & \rot{Title3}
 & \rot{Title1} & \rot{Title2}
 & \rot{Title1} & \rot{Title2}
\\\hline

AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA & {} & \cmark & {} & \cmark & {} & {} & & \cmark & \cmark & {} \\
\hline
Row2 & \cmark & {} & {} & \cmark & {} & {} & {} & \cmark & \cmark & {} \\
\hline
Row3 & {} & \cmark & {} & \cmark & {} & {} & {} & \cmark & \cmark & {} \\ 

 \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make the natural width of the columns wider than the span. I also got rid of all the empty columns as they seemed confusing.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pifont}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pifont
\newcommand{\cmark}{\ding{51}}
\newcommand{\xmark}{\ding{55}}
\newcommand*\rot[1]{\rotatebox{90}{#1 }}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\begin{table} 
\caption{MyTable}
\setlength\extrarowheight{4pt}
\centering
%\resizebox{\textwidth}{!} {% scaling tables is evil but of you do do it,. you need a % here
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth} {@{\extracolsep{\textwidth minus \textwidth}}
 l|ccc|ccc|cc|cc@{}}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{@{}c}{Column1} 
&\multicolumn{3}{c}{Column2}    
&\multicolumn{3}{c}{\makebox[0pt]{ColumnLongTitle}}
&\multicolumn{2}{c}{Column3}  
&\multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{Column4}  
\\
\cmidrule(lr){1-1} 
\cmidrule(lr){2-4} 
\cmidrule(lr){5-7}
\cmidrule(lr){8-9}
\cmidrule(lr){10-11}
\multicolumn{1}{@{}c}{}
&\rot{Title1} & \rot{Title2} & \rot{Title3} 
& \rot{Title1} & \rot{Title2} & \rot{Title3} 
& \rot{Title1} & \rot{Title2} 
& \rot{Title1} & \rot{Title2} 
\\ \hline
Row1 &  &  \cmark & & \cmark   &  & & & \cmark & \cmark &   \\
\hline
Row2 & \cmark &  &  &  \cmark   &  &  & & \cmark & \cmark &   \\
\hline
Row3 &  & \cmark & &  \cmark   &  &  & &\cmark & \cmark &   \\
\hline
\end{tabular*}


\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution with `tabularx` and `makecell`. I removed the vertical lines and the empty column.  It the column head is two widen write it in a `\thead` command, which allow breaks.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.3pt}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx, caption, makecell}
\setcellgapes{3pt}
\usepackage{pifont}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pifont
\newcommand{\cmark}{\ding{51}}
\newcommand{\xmark}{\ding{55}}
\newcommand*\rot{\rotatebox{90}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\caption{MyTable}
\centering\makegapedcells
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} l|*{3}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} |*{3}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}| *{2}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}| *{2}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}|@{}}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Column1}
&\multicolumn{3}{c}{Column2}
&\multicolumn{3}{c}{ColumnLongTitle}
&\multicolumn{2}{c}{Column3}
&\multicolumn{2}{c}{Column4}
\\
\cmidrule(lr){1-1}
\cmidrule(lr){2-4}
\cmidrule(lr){5-7}
\cmidrule(lr){8-9}
\cmidrule(lr){10-11}
\addlinespace
 &\rot{Title1} & \rot{Title2} & \rot{Title3}
 & \rot{Title1} & \rot{Title2} & \rot{Title3}
 & \rot{Title1} & \rot{Title2}
 & \rot{Title1} & \rot{Title2}
\\\hline
Row1 & {} & \cmark & {} & \cmark & {} & {} & & \cmark & \cmark & {} \\
\hline
Row2 & \cmark & {} & {} & \cmark & {} & {} & {} & \cmark & \cmark & {} \\
\hline
Row3 & {} & \cmark & {} & \cmark & {} & {} & {} & \cmark & \cmark & {} \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A variant, if cells in the first column contain longer text: the first column is a `X` type column, twice as wide as the `10 other`X`columns in the cell. Also, I loaded the`geometry package, for more sensible horizontal margins if you don't have marginal notes:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx, caption, makecell}
\setcellgapes{3pt}
\newcolumntype{Y}{ >{\hsize=2\hsize\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{Z}{ >{\hsize=0.9\hsize\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{pifont}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pifont
\newcommand{\cmark}{\ding{51}}
\newcommand{\xmark}{\ding{55}}
\newcommand*\rot{\rotatebox{90}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\caption{MyTable}
\centering\makegapedcells
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}Y|*{3}{Z} |*{3}{Z}| *{2}{Z}| *{2}{Z}|@{}}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Column1}
&\multicolumn{3}{c}{Column2}
&\multicolumn{3}{c}{ColumnLongTitle}
&\multicolumn{2}{c}{Column3}
&\multicolumn{2}{c}{Column4}
\\
\cmidrule(lr){1-1}
\cmidrule(lr){2-4}
\cmidrule(lr){5-7}
\cmidrule(lr){8-9}
\cmidrule(lr){10-11}
\addlinespace
 &\rot{Title1} & \rot{Title2} & \rot{Title3}
 & \rot{Title1} & \rot{Title2} & \rot{Title3}
 & \rot{Title1} & \rot{Title2}
 & \rot{Title1} & \rot{Title2}
\\\hline

AA AAA AAA AA AA AAA AAA AAA AAA & {} & \cmark & {} & \cmark & {} & {} & & \cmark & \cmark & {} \\
\hline
Row2 & \cmark & {} & {} & \cmark & {} & {} & {} & \cmark & \cmark & {} \\
\hline
Row3 & {} & \cmark & {} & \cmark & {} & {} & {} & \cmark & \cmark & {} \\

 \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can't you maintain the vertical lines as I originally posted? I tried, things got messy.

Comment: I can, but it makes the table preamble a little more complex. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I added an update. Still can not get what must be.

Comment: @user6875880: I've added an answer to take your update into account.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly modified *Bernard* answer:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, tabularx}
\setcellgapes{3pt}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\setlength\hsize{0.7\hsize}\centering  \arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\setlength\hsize{3.0\hsize}\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\newcommand\mcn[2]{\multicolumn{#1}{c}{#2}}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{pifont}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pifont
\newcommand{\cmark}{\ding{51}}
\newcommand{\xmark}{\ding{55}}

\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.3pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
    \caption{My Table}
\centering
\makegapedcells
\settowidth\rotheadsize{\theadfont Title 3}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} L | *{3}{C} | *{3}{C} | *{2}{C} | *{2}{C} @{}}
    \hline
\mcn{1}{Column1}    &   \mcn{3}{Column2}    &   \mcn{3}{ColumnLongTitle}
        &   \mcn{2}{Column3}    &   \mcn{2}{Column4}                    \\
\cmidrule(lr){1-1}\cmidrule(lr){2-4}\cmidrule(lr){5-7}
    \cmidrule(lr){8-9}\cmidrule(lr){10-11}
 & \rothead{Title1} & \rothead{Title2} & \rothead{Title3}
 & \rothead{Title1} & \rothead{Title2} & \rothead{Title3}
 & \rothead{Title1} & \rothead{Title2}
 & \rothead{Title1} & \rothead{Title2}                                  \\
    \hline
AAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAA
      &          & \cmark &   & \cmark &   &   &   & \cmark & \cmark &   \\
    \hline
Row 2 & \cmark   &        &   & \cmark &   &   &   & \cmark & \cmark &   \\
    \hline
Row 3 &          & \cmark &   & \cmark &   &   &   & \cmark & \cmark &   \\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Main differences:

- for rotated headers is used `\rothead` from package `makecell`
- defined new command `\mcn{...}{...}` as shortcut for `\multicolumn{...}{c}{...}`
- deleted all surplus curly braces in empty cells

[image]